# Solaris 10,print only banner

Tags: solaris, lp

I have a remote printer by cups(cups-pdf virtual printer) on linux server.
BSD,Hp-ux and linux works fine,on solaris 10 i have
this problem,print the banner only,not the text of file.
I have configured the printer like this

```
svcadm disable svc:/application/print/server:default
svcadm enable svc:/application/print/server:default
lpadmin -x cupsprinter||echo
lpadmin -p cupsprinter -v /dev/null
lpadmin -p cupsprinter -m netstandard
lpadmin -p cupsprinter -o dest=remotesite -o protocol=bsd -o timeout=22
lpadmin -d cupsprinter
lpadmin -p cupsprinter -I postscript -T PS
accept cupsprinter
/usr/bin/enable cupsprinter
```

On linux server nothing on error log
What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found.
On linux if use inetd this line print correct even from unix clients

```
printer         stream  tcp     nowait  lp      /usr/lib64/cups/daemon/cups-lpd cups-lpd -o document-format=application/octet-stream -o job-sheets=none,none
```

The important part is "-o document-format=application/octet-stream -o job-sheets=none,none"

If use xinetd use this file

```
service printer
    {
        socket_type = stream
        protocol = tcp
        wait = no
        user = lp
        server = /usr/lib64/cups/daemon/cups-lpd
        server_args = -o document-format=application/octet-stream -o job-sheets=none,none
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a larger text file as a test instead, especially if your test text file is a short, under-one-page document. Printer daemon could be awaiting a form feed before printing first page following the banner. Recall similar issue with Solaris years ago; i.e., 1999.

From your comment, sounds you aren't getting any output even from a larger file. Perhaps try sending a formfeed character directly.

The dev/null uri may also be worth modifying, at least for testing, specifying a JetDirect or other location instead:

```
lpinfo -v

socket://192.168.0.105
```

Comment: print /etc/termcap print only the banner